# SQL correct query or not

Tags: sql

[image: table relationships]

given these relationships, how could you query the following:
The tourists (name and email) that booked **at least a pension** whose **rating is greater than 9**, but **didn't book any 3 star hotel** with a **rating less than 9**.

Is the following correct?

```
SELECT Tourists.name, Tourists.email
FROM Tourists
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM Bookings
    INNER JOIN Tourists ON Bookings.touristId=Tourists.id 
    INNER JOIN AccomodationEstablishments ON Bookings.accEstId=AccomodationEstablishments.id
    INNER JOIN AccomodationTypes ON AccomodationEstablishments.accType=AccomodationTypes.id 
    WHERE   AccomodationTypes.name = 'Pension' AND 
        AccomodationEstablishments.rating > 9
) AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM Bookings
    INNER JOIN Tourists ON Bookings.touristId=Tourists.id 
    INNER JOIN AccomodationEstablishments ON Bookings.accEstId=AccomodationEstablishments.id
    INNER JOIN AccomodationTypes ON AccomodationEstablishments.accType=AccomodationTypes.id 
    WHERE   AccomodationTypes.name = 'Hotel' AND 
        AccomodationEstablishments.noOfStars = 3 AND 
        AccomodationEstablishments.rating < 9
)
```

Comment: Does it yield an error?  Look at using SQLFiddle to test your query.

Comment: Does it return what you want?

Comment: Use self join over sub query.....

Comment: It is only an execise, I don't have an actual DB with data in it

Comment: @ankit-bajpai, how would this look like with self join?

Comment: You are fetching the  data from  Tourists table and using this table in sub query also, So you can use self join here.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT t.name, t.email
FROM Bookings b INNER JOIN
     Tourists t
     ON b.touristId = t.id INNER JOIN
     AccomodationEstablishments ae
     ON b.accEstId = ae.id INNER JOIN
     AccomodationTypes a
     ON ae.accType = a.id 
GROUP BY t.name, t.email
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN a.name = 'Pension' AND ae.rating > 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(a.name = 'Hotel' AND ae.noOfStars = 3 AND ae.rating < 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)= 0;
```

Your method also works, but you probably need `t.id` in the subqueries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GordonLinoff ! I like this shorter version. I did not use the keywords: CASE, WHEN, THEN, ELSE, END before.
Maybe http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-case.html can help me out here with more information, as https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ did not contain these.